# Python MySQLdb query with variable and "time_format(time, '%H:%i')"

Tags: python, mysql-python

Been struggling for hours and having searched the Internet to no avail. I tried every suggestion from stackoverflow (use '%%', change the ',' before '(val)' to '%', bracket the '%s' with "'" etc) but no joy (see error messages below).

Codes:

```
timeList = ['09:31', '09:32', '09:33', '09:34', '09:35']
for z, val in enumerate(timeList):
   selectToday = dbConnect.cursor()
   selectToday.execute('''SELECT sec_code, date, time, price_nom, price_change_percent, vol \
        FROM tab_metrics \
        WHERE date = '2013-04-30' \
        AND time_format(time, '%H:%i') = %s \
        AND price_nom > 1 \
        ORDER BY sec_code''', (val))
```

Could it be because there's '%H:%i' (I need to ignore the seconds in the database)in the query? If so, how do I fix this? Thanks for helping.

All sort of errors while I was experimenting:

> ValueError: unsupported format character 'H' (0x48) at index 213
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the full traceback, I can't be sure, but I suspect `MySQLdb` is using `sprintf()`-style string interpolation on your query string to insert the necessary parameters.

In which case, you'll have to escape any `%` characters which should be sent to MySQL literally, by changing them to `%%`, so...

```
timeList = ['09:31', '09:32', '09:33', '09:34', '09:35']
for z, val in enumerate(timeList):
   selectToday = dbConnect.cursor()
   selectToday.execute("""SELECT sec_code, date, time, price_nom, price_change_percent, vol \
        FROM tab_metrics \
        WHERE date = '2013-04-30' \
        AND time_format(time, '%%H:%%i') = %s \
        AND price_nom > 1 \
        ORDER BY sec_code""", (val))
```

...should do the trick.